# Java ssh execution

Tags: java, ssh

В результате выполнения нижеприведенного кода в консоли остается пустота.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ssh -V");
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader (in);

String line;
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Если написать "exec("date")" или exec("ls"), то консоль правильно заполняется данными.

Может быть у кого-то будут идеи, в чем проблема?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё потому, что ssh -V печатает не в stdout, а в stderr. Чтобы читать оттуда, надо открыть другой стрим через [getErrorStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream%28%29).

Comment: Тем, кто читает доки в качестве бонуса там ссылка, рассказывающая, как объединить stdout и stderr нахаляву.